# «Ты мне надоел тысячу лет!»

Tags: лексика, управление

«*Безусловно, он не был вполне нормален в эту минуту. Последняя фраза "надоел тысячу лет" убедила меня*» (Вениамин Каверин. Два капитана. Ч. 8, гл. 7).

Капитан не поясняет, чем фраза так убедила его. А вопрос остаётся.

Comment: Не наблюдается такого устойчивого выражения. Поисковики выводят на одного автора. Видимо, эмоции захлестнули персонажа, и тот выразился нескладно - автор же может себе такое позволить. Видимо, говоривший подразумевал: "надоел так, что тысячу лет бы тебя не видел!"

Answer (score 2):

**Ты мне надоел тысячу лет!**

Грамматика неверная, но зато очень эмоционально и выразительно. По крайней мере, мне эта фраза из книги запомнилась. Возможно, грамматическая неточность как раз и определяет состояние героя.

Смысл, возможно, такой:
*Ты мне надоел **так**, будто надоедал **тысячу лет**.*

Answer (score 1):

> – Я остался, чтобы сказать, что ты мешал мне всегда и везде. Каждый
>   день, каждый час! Ты мне надоел смертельно, безумно! Ты мне надоел
>   тысячу лет!

Ну если рассматривать лингвистические мотивы, то "тысячу лет" - протяженность во времени, она всегда требует несовершенного вида глагола. Человек с родным русским не мог так выразиться будучи в нормальном состоянии. Или должен был хотя бы заметить свою оговорку.

Это как минимум. Что уж там ещё было или могло быть - это надо было бы у Каверина спрашивать. Но его уже не спросишь.